# how to login and post data to web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Problem Description:- i am trying to call web services of different domain(i.e. Systems are not connected locally with each other) so i am getting error:-"POST https://ss.atlassian.net/secure/MyJiraHome.jspa 401 ()".

```
function send()
{
    Username="j.er";
    Password="Sa@";
    var urlvariable;
    urlvariable = "text";
    var ItemJSON;
    ItemJSON = {
                "fields": {
                    "customfield_10053": {
                        "value": "800"
                    }
                }
            };
    URL = "https://ss.ian.net";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa('Username:Password')); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.send(ItemJSON);
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
function callbackFunction(xmlhttp) 
{
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<Button onClick='send();'>send</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read about [401 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) may be this will guide you.